# Create BSpline from knots and coefficients

Tags: python, scipy, spline, bspline

How can a spline be created if only the points and the coefficients are known? I'm using `scipy.interpolate.BSpline` here, but am open to other standard packages as well. So basically I want to be able to give someone just those short arrays of coefficients for them to be able to recreate the fit to the data. See the failed red-dashed curve below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import BSpline, LSQUnivariateSpline

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50) # x-data
y = np.exp(-(x-5)**2/4)    # y-data

# define the knot positions

t = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]

# get spline fit

s1 = LSQUnivariateSpline(x, y, t)

x2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 200) # new x-grid
y2 = s1(x2) # evaluate spline on that new grid

# FAILED: try to construct BSpline using the knots and coefficients

k = s1.get_knots()
c = s1.get_coeffs()
s2 = BSpline(t,c,2)

# plotting

plt.plot(x, y, label='original')
plt.plot(t, s1(t),'o', label='knots')
plt.plot(x2, y2, '--', label='spline 1')
plt.plot(x2, s2(x2), 'r:', label='spline 2') 
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The fine print under `get_knots`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline.get_knots.html#scipy.interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline.get_knots) says:

> Internally, the knot vector contains 2*k additional boundary knots.

That means, to get a usable knot array from `get_knots`, one should add `k` copies of the left boundary knot at the beginning of array, and `k` copies of the right  boundary knot at the end. Here `k` is the degree of the spline, which is usually 3 (you asked for `LSQUnivariateSpline` of default degree, so that's 3). So:

```
kn = s1.get_knots()
kn = 3*[kn[0]] + list(kn) + 3*[kn[-1]]
c = s1.get_coeffs()
s2 = BSpline(kn, c, 3)    # not "2" as in your sample; we are working with a cubic spline
```

Now, the spline s2 is the same as s1:

[image: splines]

Equivalently, `kn = 4*[x[0]] + t + 4*[x[-1]]` would work: your `t` list contains only interior knots, so `x[0]` and `x[-1]` are added, and then each repeated `k` times more.

The mathematical reason for the repetition is that B-splines need some room to get built, due to their [inductive definition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html) which requires `(k-1)`-degree splines to exist around every interval in which we define the `k`th degree spline.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more compact way of doing it if you don't care too much about the details of the knot positions. The `tk` array is what you are looking for. Once `tk` is in hand the spline can be reproduced using the `y=splev(x,tk,der=0)` line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import splrep,splev
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

### Input data
x_arr = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)  # x-data
y_arr = np.exp(-(x_arr-5)**2/4)    # y-data
### Order of spline 
order = 3
### Make the spline 
tk = splrep(x_arr, y_arr, k=order) # Returns the knots and coefficents
### Evaluate the spline using the knots and coefficents on the domian x
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000) # new x-grid
y = splev(x, tk, der=0)
### Plot
f,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_arr, y_arr, label='original')
ax.plot(x,y,label='Spline')
ax.legend(fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```