# Create spline from knots and coefficients using scipy

Tags: scipy, julia, interpolation

I'm trying to reproduce a function from a paper, which is specified only in terms of spline knots and coefficients. After finding [this on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393145/create-bspline-from-knots-and-coefficients), given a scipy interpolation object, from its knots and coefficients, I can recreate the scipy interpolation. However, the approach fails for the function specified in the paper. To reproduce a scipy interpolation I can do this:

```
using PyCall, PyPlot, Random
Random.seed!(5)
sp = pyimport("scipy.interpolate")
x = LinRange(0,1,50)
y = (0.9 .+ 0.1rand(length(x))).*sin.(2*pi*(x.-0.5))
t = collect(x[2:2:end-1]) # knots
s1 = sp.LSQUnivariateSpline(x, y, t)
x2 = LinRange(0, 1, 200) # new x-grid
y2 = s1(x2) # evaluate spline on that new grid
figure()
plot(x, y, label="original")
plot(x2, y2, label="interp", color="k")
knots = s1.get_knots()
c = s1.get_coeffs()
newknots(knots, k) = vcat(fill(knots[1],k),knots,fill(knots[end],k)) # func for boundary knots of order k
forscipyknots = newknots(knots, 3)
s2 = sp.BSpline(forscipyknots, c, 3)
y3 = s2(x2)
plot(x2,y3,"--r", label="reconstructed \nfrom knots and coeff")
legend()
```

Which provides the following as expected:
[image]

On trying to reproduce a function (image below) with specified `knots = [.4,.4,.4,.4,.7]` and coefficients `c = [2,-5,5,2,-3,-1,2]` which is supposed to produce: 
[image]
[image]

With the below code and above knots and coefficients:

```
knots = [.4,.4,.4,.4,.7]
c = [2,-5,5,2,-3,-1,2]
forscipyknots = newknots(knots, 3)
s2 = sp.BSpline(forscipyknots, c, 3)
figure()
plot(x2, s2(x2))
```

I get the following (below) instead. I'm sure I'm messing up the boundary knots - how can I fix this? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

The inner-knot sequence `t=[0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.7]` and the parameters `c=[2,-5,5,2,-3,-1,2]` do not allow a spline to be constructed, the example contains an error (more on this later). The best you can get out of it is to remove one of the `0.4` knots and construct a quadratic (second-degree) spline as follows

```
tt = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.7,1.0,1.0,1.0]
c  = [2,-5,5,2,-3,-1,2]
s2 = BSpline(tt,c,2)
```

This produces the following graph
[image]

**Long answer:**

The knot sequence in *Example 3* contains only the inner knots, therefore, you need to add the boundary knots. Since you want to evaluate the spline on the interval `[0,1]` the full knot sequence needs to cover the points 0 and 1. The simplest is to add 0 to the beginning and 1 to the end of the sequence and replicate them as necessary according to the desired degree of the spline. A cubic (third-degree) spline would require four boundary knots (i.e. four zeros and four ones) and a quadratic spline would require three boundary knots (three zeros and three ones).

There is a problem, however. A cubic spline would require 9 parameters, while Example 3 only gives you 7. Hence, you cannot construct a cubic spline from this. With the seven parameters given, you could construct a quadratic spline, but, there, the problem is that for quadratic splines each point can only appear at most three times in the inner-knot sequence. And 0.4 appears four times (which would suggest a cubic spline). Hence, all you can do is to remove one of the 0.4 knots and construct a second-degree spline as in the short answer above.

Now I will explain what you did wrong. In the first example you obtained the knot sequence from an existing spline using `knots = s1.get_knots()`, which gave you `knots=[0,0.02,0.04,...,0.98,1]`. This sequence contains the boundary knots 0 and 1 (although only once). Hence, to construct a cubic spline, you replicated each of these three times to obtain `forscipyknots = [0,0,0,0,0.02,0.04,...,0.98,1,1,1,1]`. So far so good.

In *Example 3*, however, the knot sequence does not contain the boundary points. As you did the same as before, you ended up replicating the 0.4 and 0.7 knots three times resulting in `forscipyknots = [0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7]`. You cannot construct a spline on this sequence, whatever comes out of this is not a spline. What you needed instead was `forscipyknots = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.7,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]` (which would not have worked because you do not have enough coefficients; but you could try this with your own, for instance, `c = [1,2,-5,5,2,-3,-1,2,1]`). To do this, you needed to add 0 to the beginning and 1 to the end of the array and only then use your `newknots` function.

Just as an example, a cubic spline could look like this

```
tt = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.7,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
c  = [1,2,-5,5,2,-3,-1,2,1]
s2 = BSpline(tt,c,3)
```

[image]